# change Caps Lock key to fn key

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro

I replaced standard <kbd>fn</kbd> key by left <kbd>control</kbd>, left <kbd>control</kbd> by another useful key.

And as far as I don't use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key in everyday life, I decided to replace <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key by <kbd>fn</kbd>.

I use for this purpose [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en).

[image: change Caps Lock to fn key in PCKeyboardHack]

I just inputed number `63` (which corresponds to <kbd>fn</kbd>) in `Change Caps Lock` row.

But now my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> don't do nothing: neither `CapsLock`ing nor <kbd>fn</kbd> key work.

When I change <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key by `forward delete` for example (117 code) - it is ok. And <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> starts work as `forward delete` key.

[image: change Caps Lock to forward delete in PCKeyboardHack]

But I need to set <kbd>fn</kbd> to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key.

**UPDATE**

I have noticed in KeyRemap4MacBook EventViewer: when I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>...

[image: KeyRemap4MacBook EventViewer]

... I get `control_l` keycode. But in fact it don't work even as `control_l` (I checked).

Why it shows `control_l`? Maybe because I have changed <kbd>fn</kbd> key to left <kbd>control</kbd> in `KeyRemap4MacBook` app.

[image: fn to control_l in KeyRemap4MacBook]

When I uncheck this checkbox and watch in `EventViewer` on <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> clicking again: I see `Fn` code on output.

[image: fn logged in eventViewer but in fact not working]

But in fact it does not work as <kbd>Fn</kbd> (I check it on <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>)

**Update 2**

I disabled <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd>

[image: CAPS LOCK - no action]

In PCKeyboardHack set <kbd>F19</kbd> to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>

[image: F19 to Caps LOCK]

In `KeyRemap4MacBook` remap <kbd>F19</kbd> to <kbd>fn</kbd>

```
<item>
    <name>f19_to_fn</name>
    <identifier>f19_to_fn</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::FN</autogen>
</item>
```

[image: enable f19 to fn in PCKeyboardHack]

And now <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> works as <kbd>fn</kbd> except f1 - f12 keys. For example when I press default <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f11</kbd> I see Launchpad. When I press remapped <kbd>fn</kbd> +  <kbd>f11</kbd> I see volume down. So <kbd>f11</kbd> not working with remapped <kbd>fn</kbd>.

In other combinations like <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> = `forward delete` remapped <kbd>fn</kbd> works well.

Comment: Are you pressing an actual function key (F1-F19) with the function key (FN)? normally for it to work you need to press `FN + F1-19`.

Comment: yes I test fn key with `forward delete`. I press `fn` + `delete`. When I have standard `fn` key I can forward delete and when I set `caps lock` to `fn` key, I cannot forward delete pressing `caps lock + backspace`

Answer (score 3):

Just changing caps lock to key code 63 with PCKeyboardHack works for me. Have you tried setting caps lock no action from System Preferences?

[image]

You could also try to use PCKeyboardHack to for example change caps lock to F19 and then use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::FN</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you! Caps Lock to fn works  except f1 - f12 keys (Please see update 2)

Answer (score 1):

Brett Terpstra covered this in a December 2012 article about remapping the caps lock key.

http://brettterpstra.com/2012/12/08/a-useful-caps-lock-key/

Answer (score 0):

Apple has posted a Note on Key Remapping for macOS 10.12, which can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2450/_index.html

On this page, you can find a terminal command as well as a chart of all the button values.

And if you are into programming, they even provide a little Objective-C code example.